# TKinter Button Application Destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am trying to make a Stepmania (DDR knockoff game) parser GUI that shows all of the data it collects in the form of graphs using tkinter! I am very new to tkinter so I don't really understand how to make the buttons function so I keep getting this error message that says "command: application has been destroyed" and I do not know how to fix it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import glob



root = Tk()

e = Entry(root, width = 50)
e.pack()
root.title("Insert GUI Title Here")
root.geometry('600x400+50+50')
root.resizable(False, False)
nameDirections = []
directions = []
# nameDirections hold names of types of arrows the parser is counting
# directions holds the number of each type of arrow the parser is counting



def openSmFile():
    folPath = filedialog.askdirectory()
    return folPath


root.mainloop()


def checkDirections():
    folPath = openSmFile()
    for fpath in glob.iglob(f'{folPath}/*'):
        if (fpath.endswith('.sm')):
            file = open(fpath,"r")
            lines = []
            lines = file.readlines()

            left = 0
            down = 0
            up = 0
            right = 0
            beats = 0

            for line in lines:  
                i = 0
                if not ("," in  line or "." in line or "#" in line or ";" in line or "-" in line or line == ""):
                    for alpha in line:
                        if i == 0 and alpha != "0":
                            left += 1
                        if i == 1 and alpha != "0":
                            down += 1
                        if i == 2 and alpha != "0":
                            up += 1
                        if i == 3 and alpha != "0":
                            right += 1
                        i += 1
                        beats += 1
                
            print ("There are " + str(left) + " lefts in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(down) + " downs in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(up) + " ups in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(right) + " rights in this song.")
            print ("There are " + str(beats) + " beats.")
            nameDirections = ["left", "down", "up", "right"]
            directions = [left, down, up, right] 

#sm Parser
#It works perfectly fine
       

runThrough = Button(
    root,
    padx=50, 
    pady=50, 
    text="Click to print number of each arrow", 
    command=checkDirections
)

# Runs the parser 

runThrough.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

def barGraph():
    LabelBar = Label(root, text = "Bar Activated")
    LabelBar.pack()
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.title("Directions")
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ypos = np.arange(len(nameDirections))
    plt.bar(nameDirections, directions)
    plt.show()

# Shows a bar graph

def ILovePie():
    LabelPie = Label(root, text = "Pie Activated")
    LabelPie.pack()
    plt.title("Directions")
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ypos = np.arange(len(nameDirections))
    plt.pie(directions, labels = nameDirections,autopct='%1.1f%%',
    shadow=True, startangle=90)
    plt.show()

# Shows a pie graph

barGraph = Button(root, text = "Click to show a bar graph", padx = 50, pady = 50, command = barGraph())
barGraph.grid(row = 1, column = 5)

# Bar graph button
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put the mainloop() at the end of the code, otherwise you are executing the program without all the essential widgets and information.

```
root = Tk()
# All previous functions and widgets here

# At the bottom of your code should be:
root.mainloop()
```